# Is there a way to SELECT a column but not GROUP BY it using T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I am trying to exclude transactions that net to zero, while keeping the transactions, along with their uniqueidentifier, that do not net to zero.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
   create table dbo.some_GL_table
(
  GLIndex        uniqueidentifier       not null ,
  InvoiceNum     string                 not null ,
  PayeeNum       string                 not null ,
  TranAmount     decimal                not null ,
)
```

My current code looks like this:

```
SELECT
  MAX(GL.GLIndex) AS GLIndex
, GL.InvoiceNum
, GL.PayeeNum
, SUM(GL.TranAmount) AS TranNet
FROM dbo.some_GL_table AS GL
GROUP BY
  GL.InvoiceNum
, GL.PayeeNum
HAVING SUM(GL.TranAmount) <> 0
```

Each transaction has a unique GLIndex, so adding GLIndex to the GROUP BY will no longer collapse and kick out (via the GROUP BY & HAVING) transactions that have the same InvoiceNum & PayeeNum and net to zero.

Someone on another thread suggested using MAX() so that GLIndex does not have to go into the GROUP BY. This actually messed up the output because it did select the MAX GLIndex when the InvoiceNum & PayeeNum were the same but did not net to zero.

Here is a picture to help visualize what's going on. The yellow highlights have the same InvoiceNum and PayeeNum and the SUM of TranNet nets to zero. These should be excluded from the results. However, the unhighlighted rows have the same InvoiceNum and PayeeNum but do NOT net to zero. They should be included in the results. The problem is the TranNet will get summed and the two transactions will get collapsed to one row and only the MAX GLIndex will be chosen and get assigned to the row. Is there a way to keep these two unhighlighted transactions as separate rows with their individual GLIndexes? I need the GLIndexes to join on later in the query.

[SampleGLData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUQJT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using a CTE. You make a cte/subquery with the tran amounts summed, and then join to it and remove the values with a 0 total:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT 
InvoiceNum, 
PayeeNum, 
SUM(TranAmount) AS TranAmount

FROM some_GL_table

GROUP BY 
InvoiceNum, 
PayeeNum
)

select t.*
from some_GL_table t
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t.InvoiceNum = t2.InvoiceNum
    AND t.PayeeNum = t2.PayeeNum
    AND t2.TranAmount <> 0
```

Comment: This answer was exactly what I needed and was the easiest to understand. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from some_GL_table t
where not exists (select 1
                  from some_GL_table t2
                  where t2.payeenum = t.payeenum and
                        t2.trannet = - t.trannet
                 );
```

Comment: @dfundako . . . That was a typo.  One should obviously be `t.trannet`.

Comment: I meant the logic didn't work. The equality check doesn't produce the correct output.

Comment: @dfundako . . . That could depend on the data types.  You might want:  `abs(t2.trannet + t.trannet) < 0.001`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach

```
with sum_cte as (
    select *, sum(TranAmount) over (partition by InvoiceNum, PayeeNum 
                                    order by (select null)) sum_ta
    from dbo.some_GL_table)
select *
from sum_cte
where sum_ta>0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    GL.GLIndex
  , GL.InvoiceNum
  , GL.PayeeNum
  , SUM(GL.TranAmount) AS TranNet
  FROM dbo.some_GL_table AS GL
  GROUP BY
    GL.GLIndex
  , GL.InvoiceNum
  , GL.PayeeNum
  HAVING SUM(GL.TranAmount) <> 0
```